# Tests with Probot API from GitHub and Smee failing to accept payload?

Tags: javascript, github, probot

I'm posting some sample data to my Smee endpoint and I am also running a local instance of my ProBot app. I get a bad request in my bot logs and I see this is the Smee response:

```
  { Error: cannot POST / (400)
at Response.toError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/smee-client/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/response.js:94:15)
at ResponseBase._setStatusProperties (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/smee-client/node_modules/superagent/lib/response-base.js:123:16)
at new Response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/smee-client/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/response.js:41:8)
at Request._emitResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/smee-client/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:752:20)
at IncomingMessage.parser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/smee-client/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:916:38)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    status: 400,
    text: 'Required headers missing: x-github-event, x-github-delivery',
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/' },
```

How can I get these header values to test with in my app? Not sure if it's me, but the documentation doesn't note this anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I used https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output to throw in the payload as the body and my secret and the hash was valid!